# Unable to transfer file from windows subsystem for linux to remote server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, scp

I am currently working on a windows 10 laptop. I have installed the ubuntu subsystem (instead of PUTTY) in it to access the remote server. When I launch the ubuntu subsystem from my windows start menu, it opens with a command prompt user@PC0BCD-PC

The remote server is a Linux server as well.

In addition, I am connected to a VPN. If I don't connect to the VPN, I will not be able to login to the remote server.

So, what I would like to do is transfer the file from my local windows ubuntu subsystem to the remote server

So, i tried the below command and got an error as shown below

```
scp /mnt/c/Users/test/Downloads/DC_cond.csv test@172.XX.YYY.Z:/home/test/cond_occ.csv

ssh: connect to host 172.XX.YYY.Z port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable
lost connection
```

`/mnt/c/Users/....` indicates the path in my local system whereas `test@172.XX.YYY.Z` indicates my remote server address.

when I type `telnet 172.XX.YYY.Z 22` in my WSL, it just says `Trying 172.XX.YYY.Z` whereas when I SSH into remote server and type `telnet 172.XX.YYY.Z 22`, it produces output for telnet command

Am unable to transfer files from remote server to local system as well.

Can help me with this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122487/discussion-on-question-by-the-great-unable-to-transfer-file-from-windows-subsyst).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, we discovered that the "core issue" was that you were able to access the server when `ssh`, and from there you could `scp`.  But when attempting to `scp` directly into the server from your WSL session on the VPN, it was not accessible.

For future readers, there could be several (other) reasons for `scp` not working when `ssh` does:

- There could be a server issue.  Some servers running certain versions of `libssh2` are reported to have an issue with `scp`, although that has been fixed for a while, so it would be rare to see this.
- The shell startup files on the server could be emitting some text.  This would work with an interactive `ssh` session, but would cause issues with `scp`.  However, the error messages that you are seeing aren't quite aligned with that.

It turns out, it seems, that you were using the hostname with `ssh`, but you were attempting to use the IP address with `scp`.  The hostname worked, because you have the following in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server_1
Hostname 172.xx.yyy.z
User test
ProxyCommand ssh -q -a pitunnel -W %h:%p
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

This allowed the `ssh server_1` to use the `ProxyCommand` to connect *through* a server on the VPN named `pitunnel` *to* `server_1`.

While you already discovered that you can simply use the `server_1` hostname with `scp` to get it to work (since it also reads the same `~/.ssh/config`), you should be able to also modify the config to allow access hostname *and* IP.  Just change the first line to be:

```
Host server_1 172.xx.yyy.z
```

This tells `ssh` and `scp` to use the settings below for *both* hostname and IP.

One additional note.  You are smart to obscure the IP address, but it likely isn't necessary in this case.  If `xx` is between 16 and 31, then the IP address is on what is known as a "Private Internet" network.  It's just like the `192.168.1.1` type addresses that you see on your home router.  *Everyone* can use the same IP ranges, because they aren't routable over the public Internet.

That's why you have to connect to the VPN and use a proxy to access it.  It isn't on the public Internet to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`openssh-server` might not be installed on the server or port 22 might be firewalled by the server or the VPN router.

To check the latter you could change the port to use in the openssh-server config on the server just add/replace the Port configuration to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Port 80
```

or any port you are sure is not blocked by the firewall.

Than use `ssh -p 80 <some_user>@<some_ip>`

You could use any other port as well (just swap out 80 for another reasonable port), but port 80 is most likely not restricted.

If you already have a service binding to port 80 you will run into trouble changing the configuration. To list all used port on the server you can use `ss` or `netstat` as described by Pierre ALBARÈDE in his comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. Upvoted. May I check how can I find out which port is not blocked by firewall? I don't have sudo access... In my ssh_config, we have port 22...You want me to change that to port 80? I should just edit the `sshd_config` file?

Comment: Try `ss` or `netstat` see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-open-ports-in-linux-using-the-cli/

Comment: @TheGreat The best way to figure this out would probably be to ask the network administrator about this, changing the port in the config is a way to debug this on your own.